# How to separate timestamp in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, split, timestamp, google-sheets-formula

In googlesheet, I have a timestamp in this format

```
March 12, 2021, 9:54 PM
```

I need to split it to

```
2021-03-12
```

And in another column:

```
9:54 PM
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using US locale for GS then use following formulas for date:

```
=TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(A1,","),,{1,2}),"yyyy-MM-dd")
```

and for time:

```
=TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(A1,","),,3),"h:mm AM/PM")
```

[image]